# Clearing cache in IE10+ through jsp pages

Tags: caching, internet-explorer-10

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store">
<meta http-equiv=" Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

I have tried using this cache control tag in all my jsp pages.
But the data in the pages is **not being refreshed** while navigating from one page to another in **IE10** unless I refresh the page or clear the cache manually everytime. There is no such refresh issue in **chrome and firefox**. I used
window.location.replace() for navigation between pages.

What else can be done for clearing cache in IE10+ through jsp pages?